# How can one use CSS to prevent hyphens from causing a string to be broken in an HTML textarea?

Tags: html, css, text, textarea, line-breaks

**Using CSS (only)**, how can one prevent hyphens from causing a string to be broken in a `textarea`?

In the following minimal reproducible example, the `textarea` will show:

```
margin-block-end: 20em; 
color: red; margin-block-
start: 50em;
```

But, without adding newlines (or carriage returns), I want the `textarea` to show:

```
margin-block-end: 20em; 
color: red;
margin-block-start: 50em;
```

What CSS can be used to accomplish this?

Note that I must use CSS because I am using the ***custom CSS*** function of an existing [WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/What_are_WebExtensions).

This is what I have so far:

```css
textarea {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 17em;
  word-break: unset !important;
  word-wrap: unset !important;
  overflow-wrap: unset !important;
  hyphens: unset !important;
}
```

```html
<textarea>margin-block-end: 20em; color: red; margin-block-start: 50em;</textarea>
```

Comment: So am I right in thinking that you cannot change anything in the HTML/the text string?

Comment: I don't see that being done using CSS alone.

Comment: @avia agreed - probably can't be done by CSS alone as things seem to stand - interesting discussion e.g. at https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3434https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3434

Comment: Yes, and your link contains the URL twice in your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just ad `white-space: nowrap` property. You'll heave to add breaklines with `&#13;&#10;`

```css
textarea {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 17em;
  word-break: unset !important;
  word-wrap: unset !important;
  overflow-wrap: unset !important;
  hyphens: unset !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<textarea>margin-block-end: 20em;&#13;&#10;color: red;&#13;&#10;margin-block-start: 50em;</textarea>
```

Comment: Oh I just saw you won't use line breaks. I fiddled around and it doesn't seem possible mainly because of the space between after the : . You'll probably need to beautify with js